# linkedin-api SSO Login give 500Internal Server Error

Tags: linkedin-api

I want use SSO of linkeding to my app,
this is the generated url after click on my app button

```
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://xx.com/auth/linkedin/callback&scope=r_emailaddress&state=zSawZUCzXkct8HpTien40Q&client_id=yyyyyyy
```

redirect_uri and client_id is correct but
the result is

```
500 Internal Server Error
```